# Error trying to remove duplicate element from sorted Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

Why is my code giving a segmentation fault?

The code runs perfectly for some test cases, but after a few it starts giving a segmentation fault

```
Node *remove(Node *curr){
    Node *temp=curr;
    while(curr->data==curr->next->data){
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    temp->next=curr->next;
    delete(curr);
    return temp->next;
}

//Function to remove duplicates from sorted linked list.
Node *removeDuplicates(Node *head)
{
    // your code goes here
    Node *curr=head;
    while(curr->next!=NULL){
        if(curr->data == curr->next->data){
            curr=remove(curr);
        }
        else{
            curr=curr->next;
        }     
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: It would be good, if you would share on which TC you are seeing SEGFAULT

Comment: `curr=remove(curr);` doesn't modify the actual pointer you acquired the value of `curr` from in the first place. That's the fundamental issue. A pointer-to-pointer solution will solve this problem, btw. The whole point of this is to remove running duplicates, right?

Comment: Both functions have incorrect logic and need to be rewritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be crossing purpose with these functions, and you're note retaining your proper target for your potentially updated duplicate consolidation.

I'm gonna change the name to `removeNode` for several reasons, one of which is to avoid confusing it with `std::remove` that wouldn't be a problem if you hadn't inadvisably pulled the entire `std` namespace into play) The function should delete **a** (singular) node and return the node after (if there is one). It isn't a particularly helpful function to be honest, since all it should do is this:

```
Node *removeNode(Node *curr)
{
    if (curr)
    {
        Node *tmp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
    return curr;
}
```

Pretty boring, but it gets the job done. Now, we can use that to remove duplicates by way of an efficient pointer-to-pointer approach:

```
Node *removeDuplicates(Node *head)
{
    Node **pp = &head;
    while (*pp && (*pp)->next)
    {
        if ((*pp)->data == (*pp)->next->data)
        {
            *pp = removeNode(*pp);
        }
        else
        {
            pp = &(*pp)->next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

And that's it. A test jig that exhibits how this works is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

void print(const Node *p, std::ostream& outp = std::cout)
{
    if (p)
    {
        for (; p; p=p->next)
        {
            outp << p->data << ' ';
        }
        outp << '\n';
    }
}

Node *insertSorted(Node *head, int value)
{
    Node **pp = &head;
    
    while (*pp && (*pp)->data < value)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    
    Node *p = new Node;
    p->data = value;
    p->next = *pp;
    *pp = p;

    return head;
}

Node *removeNode(Node *curr)
{
    if (curr)
    {
        Node *tmp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
    return curr;
}

Node *removeDuplicates(Node *head)
{
    Node **pp = &head;
    while (*pp && (*pp)->next)
    {
        if ((*pp)->data == (*pp)->next->data)
        {
            *pp = removeNode(*pp);
        }
        else
        {
            pp = &(*pp)->next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}

void removeAll(Node *head)
{
    while (head)
    {
        Node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rng{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1,50);
    Node *head = nullptr;

    for (int i=0; i<30; ++i)
        head = insertSorted(head, dist(rng));
    print(head);

    head = removeDuplicates(head);
    print(head);
    removeAll(head);
}
```

**Output** (varies)

```
2 4 4 4 6 7 7 8 18 18 19 23 26 27 29 31 32 33 34 34 36 36 37 37 38 40 43 44 46 49 
2 4 6 7 8 18 19 23 26 27 29 31 32 33 34 36 37 38 40 43 44 46 49
```

Comment: why are we using a double pointer and how in the remove function node before temp is still linked to the LL even after deleting temp. The code works fine but plzz explain how

Comment: The purpose of double-indirection is to access the pointers *in* the list by address. not the addressed *in* the pointers; rather the addressed *of* the pointers. This allows us to march down the list, pointer at a time, and when we come to a point where we delete a node we don't have to tout around a pointer to the node whose `next` we're about to change because we are holding the very address of the `next` member itself in our pointer-to-pointer. It is efficient, and simple to code. I **strongly** urge you to single-step this in a debugger and watch the variables. It will help a LOT.